# Journey Builder Event vs Trigger

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

What is the difference between and Event and a Trigger in Journey Builder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [Trigger](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/journey_builder/triggers/) is a set of conditions that cause an interaction to run.

An [event](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/journey_builder/how_to_fire_an_event/) is a user- or administrator-initiated action that an administrator defines that must be met before an interaction is created.

Triggers listen for events, and once that event occurs, can initiate an interaction defined within Journey Builder.

Comment: But following the Journey Builder for Apps book, it creates a Trigger and then that trigger gets called via REST and the Interaction runs. There is no Event created. Or am I missing something? I'm still confused on how these are related.

Comment: Maybe Kelly or Tim can jump in here, but my understanding is that while events can be created, they don't necessarily have to be. In the Journey Builder for Apps book, the event would be the user installing the app, and giving their email address.

Comment: A Journey Builder Trigger is comprised of an event and a filter.  The event is the Automation or Event API call that will initiate an Interaction.  The filter uses the Contact data attributes to determine whether or not a contact will enter that Interaction.